# PHP OOP Print single value using Mysqli and Class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm starting to learn OOP method using classes.

If print all records my code works fine, but I'd like access to single fields in my index.php file.

With foreach and echo will print all fields, but I'd like store all my fields into a variables so print or only Name or Surname etc..

userslist.php

```
class Users extends dbh { 

    protected function getAllUsers() {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;

        if($numRows > 0) { 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

}

class ViewUsers extends Users { 

    public function showAllUsers() {

        $datas = $this->getAllUsers();

        //with echo will print all fields
        foreach($datas as $data) {
            echo $data["id"];
            echo $data["name"];
            echo $data["surname"];
            echo $data["phone"];
        }

        //I'd like store my fields in variables like this:
        foreach($datas as $data) {
            $id = $data["id"];
            $name = $data["name"];
            $surname = $data["surname"];
            $phone = $data["phone"];
        }

    }

}
```

index.php

```
$users = new ViewUsers();
$users->showAllUsers(); //how can access here to single field?
```

thanks!

Comment: This method doesn't return or display anything.

Comment: Please define what _exact_ purpose you want this `showAllUsers` method to fulfill. Right now, it is not apparent how having this would make sense in the first place - you could just work with the result of the `getAllUsers` method directly, if you want to pick specific fields/columns from specific rows.

Comment: You don't really want `ViewUsers::showAllUsers()` to display a single user, that would be weird - you probably want a new method called `showUser` to which you pass the user id (or some other unique identifier)...

Comment: Your method `getAllUsers` seems totally unnecessary too. It could simply be dine in one line with PDO.

Comment: I modified my request above, my code is based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHiu0JA9eqE  .  thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try something like that 
//create function for get all data from table and store in an array
  function getdata()
{
$sql="select * from table";

$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry) )
{
        $result[$i]= $row;
        $i++;
}
      return $result;}
   //call function in foreach loop and echo field name which you want to echo
   $function_data=getdata()
 {
 foreach($function_data as $findData)
 {
echo $findData['field_name'];
 }
}
```